# how is this solution achieved? longest increasing sub-sequence

Tags: algorithm

so i was doing some algorithm solving problems and the first questions input/output test case i am not able to understand. I am not asking here any algorithm or code, i just want to understand how `Bob` is winning ?

> Alice and Bob play the following game:
>
> 1) They choose a permutation of the first N numbers to begin with.
>
> 2) They play alternately and Alice plays first.
>
> 3) In a turn, they can remove any one remaining number from the
>   permutation.
>
> 4) The game ends when the remaining numbers form an increasing
>   sequence. The person who played the last turn (after which the
>   sequence becomes increasing) wins the game.
>
> Assuming both play optimally, who wins the game?

---

Test case
`5 3 2 1 4`

Now they say Bob will win the game.
How ?

```
alice -> remove 5
bob -> remove 3
alice -> remove 1/2 -> Wins
```

OR

```
alice -> remove 3
bob -> remove 5
alice -> remove 1/2 -> Wins
```

Comment: I suspect the key point is "Assuming both play optimally" ... are you choices for Bob's move the *best* choices?

Comment: @GregHewgill from that line, i assume that they are not going to remove a number which is in the longest increasing sub-sequence, and the longest increasing sub-sequence in this test case i see is `2`

Comment: Yeah, what it Bob took 4 in the either example?

Comment: @bigendian if bob removes 4, then the final answer will only have 1 digit, i am assuming the "playing optimally" is that we get longest answer, or do i understand that phrase wrong ? Optimally means increasing their winning chance ?

Comment: 'Play optimally' means maximising their winning chance. For Bob, that means try to achieve a decreasing sequence here, since he's the one to remove the second-to-last number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
alice -> remove 5
bob -> remove 4
alice -> remove 1/2/3
bob -> remove any remaining -> Wins
```

Comment: isnt "Playing Optimally" means that both want to finish the game in minimum number of moves ?

Comment: @Pheonix: No, playing optimally means they are both trying to win.

Comment: I think playing optimally means making the moves that make it harder for the opponent to win. In this case, bob removes 4 because the remaining sequence 3 2 1 is strictly decreasing and has odd length, meaning alice cannot win because she chooses first.

Answer (score 0):

The closest ending (with the fewest moves) is 3 4, 2 4 and 1 4. In this case Alice wins. So Bob must prevent that. The easiest way to do that is to remove 4. So basically that's Bob's strategy and it's enough to win.

Alice's strategy is to keep those two numbers on the board, so she will start with 5. After that, we know, that Bob will remove 4, which point Alice can choose any number because she will always lose.